# How to register user phone number also in Token based authentication in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I want to save user **phone number** when the user registers a form.

My register form is working right now only with 3 fields(EmailID, password, confirm password) using the following code

```
//SignUp
$('#btnSignUp').click(function () {
    console.log('Signup clicked');
    var data = {
        "Email": $('#txtSingUpEmail').val(),
        "PhoneNumber": '546789651',  //for testing I directly pass the value in JQuery
        "Password": $('#txtSignUpPassword').val(),
        "ConfirmPassword": $('#txtConfirmPassword').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ProjectName/api/Account/Register',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log('Registered Succesfully');
        $('#modalSignup').modal('hide');
        $('#exampleModalPreview').modal('show');
    }).fail(function (showError) {
        console.log('Signup failed');
        console.log('full error = '+JSON.stringify(showError));
        //$('#loginErrorMsg').text(JSON.parse(showError.responseText).error_description);
    });
});
```

**AccountController**

```
// POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

         //I add PhoneNumber parameter here

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber }; 

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

I tried by adding `PhoneNumber` variable on below class, but it never saved with phone numbers

**RegisterBindingModel class**

```
public class RegisterBindingModel   
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found the following method on `metadata`

**UserManager**

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(UserManager<,>.<SetPhoneNumberAsync>d__d9))]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public virtual Task<IdentityResult> SetPhoneNumberAsync(TKey userId, string phoneNumber);
```

so when I execute this method on `Register` method like below code. It enters the phone number where the user is created

```
// POST api/Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
[System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

     //I add PhoneNumber parameter here

    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber }; 

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    IdentityResult setPhoneNumber = await UserManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync("", model.PhoneNumber);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

> As well as it throws an error that **cannot find key**. I just take one userId(already registered userID's value) key from table. I pass it on the parameter like below, then it set's the phone number to both user(already registerd user and also newly register)

Comment: Have you checked, that the PhoneNumber property is not null in your action method?

Comment: @Marco could you please tell me which action method are you talking about?. I am new to this token based authentication. where is it located?.

Comment: In your Register method, set a breakpoint and check if `model.PhoneNumber` is null.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber }; 

IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
IdentityResult setPhoneNumber = await UserManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user.Id, model.PhoneNumber);
```